Implementing Stockfish Into Unity
I'm really struggling to implement stockfish into unity with c#, I've seen a lot of people using standard input to read off of stockfish. although, my program will freeze no matter what I do. (Right now I'm just trying to get any kind of input from stockfish, so it's kinda basic). Can anyone tell my why this freezes right after the start?  Much thanks. p.s sorry if this is the wrong place to post.
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using General;
using System.Threading;

public class UCIExtension : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Process stockfishProcess = new Process();
    private StreamWriter inputWriter;
    private StreamReader outputReader;

    private bool engineActive = false;

    public int moveTime;

    List<string> feed = new List<string>();


    public void Start()
    {
        //prepare and sync engine
        
        engineActive = true;

        // Path to the Stockfish executable
        string stockfishPath = Application.dataPath + "/Tools/Stockfish_17_x86-32.exe";
        // Start Stockfish process
        stockfishProcess.StartInfo.FileName = stockfishPath;
        stockfishProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        stockfishProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        stockfishProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        stockfishProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        
        stockfishProcess.Start();
        inputWriter = stockfishProcess.StandardInput;
        outputReader = stockfishProcess.StandardOutput;

        UnityEngine.Debug.Log(RunCommand("d", ""));
    }

    private void OnOutputReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            feed.Add(e.Data);
        }
    }

    public async Task RunCommand(string command, string conditional)
    {
        inputWriter.WriteLine(command);
        feed.Clear();

        while(true)
        {
            if(feed.Count == 0) continue;
            
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(feed[feed.Count - 1]);
            return;
            
        }
    }

I have tried async functions, tasks and multiple different ways of coding, readline, readtoend, readtoendasync, readlineasync, different stockfish commands and models, and tried redoing the script once. I was expecting stockfish to talk to unity correctly, and return the output stockfish writes, it just freezes.

You have an endless while loop that is run on the main thread .. of course it will freeze what exactly did you expect Debug.Log(Runcommand("d", "")); to print anyway? The return type is Task so if this could finish at all it would only print System.Threading.Tasks.Task ...

Have you tried to rather run this task via e.g. Task.Run(async () => await Runcommand("d", "")); ?

@derHugo Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. :)

As mentioned this
UnityEngine.Debug.Log(RunCommand("d", ""));

tries to start and run the task on the main thread synchronously.
It also makes little sense as the return type is just Task so the log would simply say
System.Threading.Tasks.Task

What you rather want to do is run this task asynchronously. For example using
Task.Run(async () => await Runcommand("d", ""));


Note further that even in a Task a never ending while with direct continue is not very optimal. Also a normal List is not thread save and not very suitable for async coding.
In your case the return condition should probably rather be the condition for the loop and do something like e.g.
// Rather use a thread save collection type!
private ConcurrentQueue<string> feed = new();

...

private void OnOutputReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        feed.Enqueue(e.Data);
    }
}

private async Task Runcommand(string command, string conditional = string.Empty)
{
    // probably makes more sense to clear your feed BEFORE submitting the command
    // otherwise - unlikely but not impossible - your command might already have yielded a result in between these lines
    feed.Clear();
    inputWriter.WriteLine(command);
    
    while(!feed.TryDequeue(out var result)
    {
        // at least wait for a bit of time before re checking
        // you can play around how often you actually need to check this - 200ms means 5 times per second
        await Task.Delay(200);
    }

    Debug.Log(result);
}

